# VSCode Flutter Dart slow suggestions

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio Code for flutter programming and not using many extensions. I loved the code completion but it's usually too slow. It takes around 1-2 seconds for showing all suggestions. Is there any solution to this problem? Here is my list of installed extensions:

[image: Installed extensions]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was told to add this config:

```
"dart.previewLsp": true,
```

which would put the plug-in into speaking the Language Server Protocol rather than a proprietary protocol, and it seems to have sped things up.

Comment: at which config?

Comment: My Mac Flutter setup's intellisense was way slower than Windows one. Added this option to Open Settings (JSON). Then reloaded and now it's fast like Windows setup.

Comment: the key is grayed out, unknown configuration?

Comment: @nesimtunc and to others who read here, previewLsp setting is long gone from the current Dart Language Extension. It's called `dart.useLsp` now. If you wish to follow this answer then you should add `"dart.useLsp": true,` but that didn't solve it for me. In fact, I disabled the LSP and it's now much faster. Just a heads up

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. In my case I have disabled many extensions for the workspace, now it's much better.

Answer (score 4):

Using "Recommended Settings" worked for me.

Steps: `Cntrl + Shift + P` > Type and select "Use Recommended Settings".

This overwrites the recommended settings for Dart.

Answer (score 4):

### Update on 14.09.2022

`dart.useLsp` key is no longer valid: [v3.48 release notes](https://dartcode.org/releases/v3-48/#v3480-2022-09-01:%7E:text=The%20dart.useLsp%20setting%20has%20been%20replaced%20by%20dart.useLegacyAnalyzerProtocol%20and%20its%20meaning%20inverted.%20This%20setting%20will%20be%20removed%20in%20a%20future%20version.)

Use this instead:

```json
"dart.useLegacyAnalyzerProtocol": true
```

---

Accepted answer and resetting the recommended language settings haven't worked out for me.

Although, I've continued to research a bit more and the [LSP](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/) part seemed promising simply because it popped out in a bunch of unrelated sources too. But instead of enabling LSP to speed things up, people suggest going in the opposite direction and disabling LSP. Specifically, a person from the Dart VSCode team (at [GitHub](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3102#issuecomment-813576808)):

> …**The only other thing I could suggest is disabling LSP but also disabling auto-import completions**…

Said settings can be set from `settings.json` like below:

```json
"dart.useLsp": false,
"dart.autoImportCompletions": false
```