# flutter in vscode: need to way a long time before ctrl + . showing suggestion popup

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

I recently have the issue that `ctrl + .` in vscode for my flutter project does not pop up suggestions immediately (need to wait a very long time). A blue process bar keeps running but nothing happens.

[image]

When I move the cursor to the error, I see "Checking for quick fix". Ideally, here should be a link to the quick fixes.
[image]

When I press `ctrl + space`, I get this
[image]

VsCode version: 1.75.0

Flutter version: 3.3.7

Dart version: 2.18.4

There are no customised settings. I am using the recommended one.

Thank you

Comment: try checking output logs and see if the one for your extension has any related messages. (View > Output)

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65376564/14945696)

Comment: Thank you @KevinM.Mansour, it looks much better after adding "dart.previewLsp": true.

Comment: @Ben Should I write an answer or you will mark this question as a duplicate?

Comment: Seems like making it as duplication makes more sense. Thanks again @KevinM.Mansour